# Access to an object which is not in the same XSD with Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

First, I have a XSD containing references to commentType object :

```
...
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" type="ref:commentType">
...
```

commentType is described as (same XSD):

```
...
<xs:complexType name="commentType" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Some text</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:any/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:dateTime" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" use="optional" default="PRODUCT">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                <xs:enumeration value="PRODUCT"/>
                <!--Several values-->
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
...
```

In the XML file I'm parsing using Jaxb, entry refers to a opDetails object, which is defined in another XSD...

```
...
<entry date="2010-03-26T10:40:27Z" type="PRODUCT">
    <opDetails xmlns="http://path/to/opDetails">
        <!--Object properties-->
    </opDetails>
...
```

(I've simplied names and structure for clarity)

Questions :

How to map correctly this other object in my code ?

I have a entry.getContent() which is a list of TinyElementImpl.

Obviously, generating classes of the 2 xsd's and trying to cast TinyElementImpl as opDetails is not an option :)

Comment: Are you importing the other xsd within your "main" xsd?

Comment: I've tried :<xsd:import namespace="http://path/to/" schemaLocation="detailsOp.xsd"/>

Comment: This(your first code block):  

`<xs:complexType>`  doesn't have a name like:  

`<xs:complexType name="something">`  

Is it within an element for example that has a name? Are you using a tool that can validate your xml as well?

Comment: Positive : All files are completly valid. (Xml Spy)
I'm not the only one to work on these files, and the people who created them are good professional :)

Comment: Ok just checking to be sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer

unmarshall works with a node too.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

My code :

```
org.w3c.dom.Node nodeEntryContent = (org.w3c.dom.Node)entry.getContent().get(0);

JAXBContext ctx;
Unmarshaller um;
opDetails dOp = null;
try {
    ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("package.of.opDetails.containing.xjc.generated.classes");
    um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    dOp = (opDetails)um.unmarshal(nodeEntryContent);
} catch (JAXBException e1) {
    System.out.println("XML parsing error" + e1.getMessage());
}
```